# Prove or disprove that $g\in L(V,V)$ exists with $f=g\circ g^{ad}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, adjoint-operators

Let $V=\mathbb C^{2,1}$ with standard scalarproduct and $f\in L(V,V)$ with $f\biggr(
 \begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\biggl)=\begin{bmatrix}
x +2y \\
2x+y
\end{bmatrix}$ 
Prove or disprove that $g\in L(V,V)$ exists with $f=g\circ g^{ad}$.

I do not see how to handle this problem. I would start to try to find such $g$ like this, set $\begin{bmatrix}
x +2y \\
2x+y
\end{bmatrix}=F$, $v=(x,y)^T, w=(a,b)^T$ then, $$ \langle f(v),w\rangle=w^HF=\langle g^{ad}(v),g^{ad}(w)\rangle$$, but how should one continue. Could someone help me here and tell me how to attack this problem?

P.S.: If needed, in the definition I am using I have  linearity in the second component and semi-linearity in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard basis is $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1}$.

This matrix is not positive because $$\det\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1} = -3 < 0$$ However, the map $g\circ g^{ad}$ is positive for any linear map $g$.

Comment: The reasoning is that  if we take the standard basis , and since $[g^{ad}]_{B,B}=[g]_{B,B}^H$. Then $f=[g]_{B,B}\cdot [g]_{B,B}^H$ and this product has to be positive definite for any $[g]_{B,B}$, but since f is not, we see that such $g$ does not exist. Is this the reasoning for your answer?

Comment: @J.D Yes, exactly.